# How can I access the original map after wrapping it with ObservableMap?

Tags: groovy, observable, observers

I've created a map and then wrapped it as an ObservableMap.  Later on, I try to access the original, unwrapped map, but I can't seem to access it.  It seems to come back null.

```
private def _swarms = [:]
private def swarms = new ObservableMap(_swarms)
...
def orig = swarms.content        // returns null
orig = swarms.mapDelegate        // returns null
```

I don't see anything else at http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/ObservableMap.html that looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot refer the `property` as a `field` in case of a `Map` interface. It will try to look for a `key` with that name and would return `null` if `key<->value` pair is absent. Try this instead:

```
def _swarms = [ a : 1 ]
def swarms = new ObservableMap( _swarms )

assert swarms.getContent() == [ a : 1 ]
assert swarms.getMapDelegate() == [ a : 1 ]

// Similar anomaly
assert !swarms.class
assert swarms.getClass().simpleName == "ObservableMap"
```

Similarly, you cannot use `.class` on `Map`. Instead `getClass()` has to be used.

Comment: Yeah, kind of obvious, isn't it?  :)  Thanks.